# AWS ApiGateway request Template Passthrough

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

i'm using Lambda -> ApiGateway with Java and i need Stage Variables.

I use the default template, provided by Amazon as Integration Request:

```
##  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html
##  This template will pass through all parameters including path, querystring, header, stage variables, and context through to the integration endpoint via the body/payload
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
"body-json" : $input.json('$'),
"params" : {
#foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
"$type" : {
    #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
    "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
}
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"stage-variables" : {
#foreach($key in $stageVariables.keySet())
"$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($stageVariables.get($key))"
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"context" : {
    "account-id" : "$context.identity.accountId",
    "api-id" : "$context.apiId",
    "api-key" : "$context.identity.apiKey",
    "authorizer-principal-id" : "$context.authorizer.principalId",
    "caller" : "$context.identity.caller",
    "cognito-authentication-provider" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider",
    "cognito-authentication-type" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationType",
    "cognito-identity-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId",
    "cognito-identity-pool-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityPoolId",
    "http-method" : "$context.httpMethod",
    "stage" : "$context.stage",
    "source-ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp",
    "user" : "$context.identity.user",
    "user-agent" : "$context.identity.userAgent",
    "user-arn" : "$context.identity.userArn",
    "request-id" : "$context.requestId",
    "resource-id" : "$context.resourceId",
    "resource-path" : "$context.resourcePath"
    }
}
```

I switch to the new Aws SDK (includes Jackson JSON Parsing now) and use this class for parsing the template data:

https://github.com/ingenieux/lambada/blob/master/lambada-runtime/src/main/java/io/ingenieux/lambada/runtime/model/PassthroughRequest.java

My Problem is now, i've i create a Unittest and let them parse an example. Everything is working fine. But when it runs in AWS, the stage-variables are not filled.

If i change "stage-variables" to "stageVariables" in the template and adjust the java class ... it's correct filled.

Why it's not working with a "-" in the property name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to diagnose the problem from looking at the template and class source that you provided.

Can you enable CloudWatch logs on your API and run you test.  This should allow you to see what API Gateway is passing to Lambda and that would let us determine if the issue is in the template or the Java class.